# Serialize an ObservableCollection used as a Jumplist ItemSource

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, observablecollection, longlistselector

I am trying to create a jumplist for a `LongListSelector`, I used the `AlphaKeyGroup` example from MS as a basis.

Once I have created my list I then want to serialize it and store it until the app is next opened.

The problem I have is that the Key is null when I deserialize the `ObservableCollection`.

I have something like this on my Main Page

```
    public ObservableCollection<AlphaKeyGroup<myClass>> myList { get; set; }
    void process()
    {
        myList = AlphaKeyGroup<myClass>.CreateGroups(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
        getItemsAndAddtoList();

        string serializedata = Serialize(myList);
    }
    void getItemsAndAddtoList()
    {
        List<myClass> templist=new List<myClass>();

        templist.Add(new myClass("Alpha","A in the jumplist"));
        templist.Add(new myClass("Beta", "B in the jumplist"));
        templist.Add(new myClass("Cappa", "C in the Jumplist"));

        addToList(templist.ToArray());

        string data = Serialize(myList);

    }
    void addToList(myClass[] items)
    {
        if (this.mainList.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            SortedLocaleGrouping slg = new SortedLocaleGrouping(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);

            foreach (myClass item in items)
            {
                int index = 0;

                if (slg.SupportsPhonetics)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    index = slg.GetGroupIndex(item.description);
                }
                if (index >= 0 && index < myList.Count)
                {
                    myList[index].Add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {

            this.mainList.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<myClass[]>(addToList), new object[] { items });
        }
    }
    public static string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(sw, obj);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
```

If I break on `return sw.ToString();` I can see something like this

```
<ArrayOfMyClass>
  <myClass>
   <description>Alpha</description>
   <data>A in the jumplist</data>
  </myClass>
</ArrayOfMyClass>
```

As you can see the key from the AlphaKeyGroup class is missing, if I then deserialise this back and set it as the LongListSelector ItemSource I get a Jumplist with No text values, just empty boxes.

```
public class myClass
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
    public myClass()
    {

    }
    public myClass(string Desc, string Data)
    {
        description = Desc;
        data = Data;
    }
}
public class AlphaKeyGroup<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public delegate string GetKeyDelegate(T item);

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public AlphaKeyGroup(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }
    public AlphaKeyGroup()
    {

    }

    public static ObservableCollection<AlphaKeyGroup<T>> CreateGroups(CultureInfo ci)
    {
        SortedLocaleGrouping slg = new SortedLocaleGrouping(ci);

        ObservableCollection<AlphaKeyGroup<T>> list = new ObservableCollection<AlphaKeyGroup<T>>();

        foreach (string key in slg.GroupDisplayNames)
        {
            list.Add(new AlphaKeyGroup<T>(key));
        }

        return list;

    }

}
```

I am sure I am missing something simple, but I couldn't find a solution, I think it is to do with the Parameterless constructor, but I am not sure, I am quite new to C#.

Comment: To answer Moks reply: Its a Windows Phone 8 project

I am already saving the data and this works perfectly fine, the issue is that the saved data does not contain the correct values (Missing Key from the AlphaKeyGroup class)

Comment: I have added a sample project that demonstrates the issue here: https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=921B4AD51918CE2E&resid=921B4AD51918CE2E%21156&authkey=AALtzshIv3CAabc if you tap the new list button, that shows the expected results.  I have set the list to load and save as I want to do it in my actual project.